# Formatting works in preview but not inside post?

Tags: support, markdown

Just curious why the formatting works in the preview. ([how would I print a pattern then print the reverse pattern next to that pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012261/how-would-i-print-a-pattern-then-print-the-reverse-pattern-next-to-that-pattern))

In preview it looks like:

[image]

While in the post it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preview just shows the *plain* body text, but the lines are formatted as *one paragraph* in markdown so shown on one line.

Someone already fixed this, but the correct method would be to indent those lines by 4 spaces, optionally prefixed by `<!-- language: lang-none -->` to disable the automatic code highlighting.

So it worked in the preview because it simply takes the first N characters of the post *source*, unrendered, but with newlines intact. That same source is not marked up to show the digits as 'preformatted'.